# Approximation in series

Tags: calculus

How to approximate $[1 - 1/(2x)]$ to $[1/(1 + (1/2x))]$ when $x$ very large. What power series should be used?. This problem is used to find the precession velocity with the Yukawa potential.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: I have to wonder if you are equipped to deal with advanced material like these subjects when you do not understand this relatively simple mathematics.  I would strongly advise learning more basic mathematics before going deeper into advanced physics.  Material like this would be taught in a physics or science undergraduate program in first year.  In general it is required that entrance to  a science BSc course requires higher level high school mathematics which would cover this material already.

Answer (score 0):

$1/(1-x)$ approximate $1+x$ when $x$ very small.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean how is

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2x}}
\end{equation}
approximated by

\begin{equation}
1-\frac{1}{2x}.
\end{equation}
Consider Taylor expanding the function

\begin{equation}
(1+x)^n
\end{equation}
around zero and only keeping terms up to first order. The first derivative is

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^n = n (1+x)^{n-1},
\end{equation}
so the expansion becomes

\begin{align}
(1+x)^n \approx & (1+x)^n |_{x=0} + n (1+x)^{n-1}|_{x=0} (x-0)\\
= & 1 + n x.
\end{align}
In your case, the function is

\begin{equation}
\left( 1+\frac{1}{2x} \right)^{-1}.
\end{equation}
The second term becomes small for $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $n=-1$, so

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2x}} \approx 1 - \frac{1}{2x}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$$1-\frac{1}{2 x}\approx 1-\frac{1}{2 x+1};\; x\to\infty$$
$$1-\frac{1}{2 x+1}=\frac{2 x}{2 x+1}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2 x}}$$
Thus
$$1-\frac{1}{2 x}\approx \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2 x}}$$